# Android Tablet Landscape and Portrait Modes

Tags: android, mobile, tablet, landscape, landscape-portrait

I want to extend my mobile app to Android Tablet as well. My mobile app supports only Portrait mode in mobile but in Tablet I want to support both Landscape and Portrait modes.

But I don't want to change modes at runtime.

For Ex. If the user opens the app with his Tablet in Landscape mode, the app should run only in Landscape mode even if he rotates to Portrait while using the app.

This is possible in iPad but I don't know if it is possible in Android Tablet.

If it is possible how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not a orthodox way, but you can achieve it like this, create 2 resource files one generic and one for sw600dp (tablet) and add a bool "istablet"

[image]

Then in your activity OnCreate method

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
How do I force the user to use a specific mode i.e., the mode in which the app was opened?

Comment: Try by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity declaration in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

you can provide default orientation in manifest file like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: I know this. This is what I have done now. Please read my post carefully

Comment: than you want both mode in tablets